# Android Studio 4.2 Canary wireless debugging is not working

Tags: android-studio, debugging, wireless, android-studio-4.1

I have installed Android Studio 4.2 Canary, but wireless debugging is not working at all (https://9to5google.com/2020/06/10/android-11-beta-1-wireless-debugging-jetpack-compose/).
I enabled it in **developer options** in mobile, even tried to connect to it using **adb** but Android Studio doesn't discover my phone.
Am I missing anything, like a plugin or something like that?

I am using Android Studio 4.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: sometimes there might be issue with "DHCP" in your device. Did you try connecting with a static IP?

Comment: on mobile or on desktop?

Comment: mobile.I had similar issue few months earlier. Have a go at it with static IP.

Comment: I tried, still not working. :|

Answer (score 0):

As a **precaution**, make sure *Developers option and wireless debugging are **enabled*** and you have **latest** SDK platform tools installed:-

1. Goto Sdk manager > SDK Platforms > check "*show package details*" (at bottom right corner.)
2. Expand the latest stable Android release (currently Tiramisu) > and check Android SDK platform (currently 33) if not already checked/ installed.
3. Hit apply and allow the installation to complete if needed.

**Fix 1**

[Try disabling and then re-enabling adb mDNS from android studio settings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179842)

**Fix 2**

Try disabling any (virtual) network adapters for VPNs or VMs (virtual machines).

These **steps are for Windows**, there **maybe a Mac equivalent** of this so try that, and **if** Macs do **not** have virtual adapters. *Try the next fix*.

You can enter this path (`Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`) in your top bar of the Control Panel, otherwise just follow these steps:

1. Go to "Control Panel" in Windows
2. Click on "Network and Internet"
3. Click on "Network and Sharing Center"
4. Click on "Change adapter settings"
5. Right-mouse click on any adapter you wish to disable

After these changes, check your Android Studio to see if disabling the adapter solved your problem.

**Fix 3**

1. Goto your `Android/sdk/platform-tools` folder.

**For Windows**, the default location is: `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
(but like me you may have moved the folder around, so check that.)

2. Open the **cmd or Terminal** (mac) there.

   - In windows you can do this by clicking the folder path in adress-bar of windows explorer, and typing cmd and hitting enter there.
   - Alternatively, you can do this by opening terminal anywhere and typing `cd [path to platform-tools directory on your PC]`

> *If your PC appers under PAIRED DEVICES on your android, then skip to
> step 6, else*

3. Find your IP address, port number, and pairing code by selecting Pair device with pairing code. Take note of the IP address, port number, and pairing code displayed on the device.
4. On terminal you opened, run `adb pair ipaddr:port`. Use the IP address and port number from above.
5. When prompted, enter the pairing code, as shown
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkxQs.png)

*P.S: these steps are also avilable [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#wireless-android11-command-line) from google, but for some reason they didn't mention the steps above.

6. After your device is sucessfully paired, run `adb connect ip:port`. the ip:port that is visible in the main page of Wireless debugging [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WlMx.png).

With This, hopefully the device will be connected.

**Sources**

- Fix 1: [An answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179842)
- Fix 2: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459227/21948834)
- Fix 3: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63034722/21948834), [This answer/image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75431685/21948834) and [1st 2 answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70905560/21948834).