# Android 11 - Wireless ADB Pairing - Windows machine

Tags: android, adb, beta

On Pixel 2 I have android 11 beta version running. The wireless adb pairing works fine from a Ubuntu machine to my phone but it fails from a Windows machine with following message

```
error: unknown host service
```

### General steps:

- Dev Options > Wireless debugging (Enabled)
- [Accept on a prompt to trust current WiFi]
- Tap: Pair device with paring code
- From computer (i.e. Windows OS), using adb from 'Platform-tools' run `adb pair 192.168.1.45:40404`
  [IP address and port is visible in your phone in the dialog after tapping Pair device with paring code.] [Tried: `.\adb pair ip:port, adb.exe pair ip:port` same error]
- [When successfully connected, the dialog box disappears on it's own (saw this behavior from Linux/Ubuntu however from windows I am not having any luck]

### Platform tools Downloads

[Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip) | [Mac](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-darwin.zip) | [Linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip)

### Connect to phone

- [Once the device is paired]
- adb connect ip:port

  - [NOT the ip:port visible in the dialog that comes on Pair device]
  - the ip:port that is visible in the main page of Wireless debugging

### Question

How can I resolve the wireless adb paring from Windows OS?

Answer (score 26):

Kill the server and try to pair. It works for me

## 1. Kill server

`./adb kill-server`

## 2. pair devices

`./adb pair ipaddr:port`

This would work

Comment: ./adb kill-server worked for me (Linux & Nothing phone (1)). Maybe I had other server running, because (although I just `sudo apt remove --purge removed android-sdk-platform-tools-common adb fastboot` outdated packages from ubuntu repository) I just ran `adb version` (from $PATH) and `./adb version` (from $HOME/...) to see differences between repos and fresh true "latest" download from developer.android.com

Comment: Yes. In Debian/Ubuntu repositories, android-platform-tools version is usually older than https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools . Currently, in Ubuntu its version is 29.0.6 and actual newer version is 33.0.3

Answer (score 3):

The issue might be the port is used by a device (maybe a program on your computer)

Check by running:

```
netstat -ano|findstr <port>
```

This will show what program is using it by showing the PID. If you found one using it, just kill the program.

Comment: I doubt as I tried several times with different ports (as android keeps giving you random ports). Good thinking though.

Comment: I tried it on my Xiaomi Mi 10 Pro with official AOSP 11 Betas, and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Restart of OS helps.
But exact reason is still unknown